# Accessing argc and argv from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, argv, argc

I encountered the following assembly version of a C code (Practical Malware Analysis by Michael Sikorski, Chapter 5). I simply do not understand how it accesses the command line parameters.

```
cmp [ebp+argc], 3
...
mov eax, [ebp+argv]
```

I understand what this code does:

```
mov ecx, [esp+4] ; argc
mov edx, [esp+8] ; argv
```

Function arguments are put on the top on stack, and they are accessed with their address relative to the top of stack. But what means `ebp+argc` and `ebp+argv`?

Comment: They would have to be defined for that assembler as `4, 8` or `8, 16` (x86_64). Are there any include files used? Which assembler?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, the book only says that is a C code in compiled form.

Comment: You need to read the section in the book before it about call functions and the stack layout (including what EBP is for). There is a diagram with how the stack frame is layed out. You'll notice in the diagram that the first argument passed is at EBP+8 and second parameter is EBP+12. Although the book doesn't explicitly say it `argc` = 8 and `argv` = 12 . They are just constants for the purpose of making the disassembly more readable.

Comment: In a 32-bit environment, If you are curious what is at EBP+0, it is the previous value of EBP that was pushed on the stack. EBP+4 is the return address that was put on the stack (will be popped of when we do a `ret`). EBP+8 and above are the arguments that were passed to our function.